# How to turn off connected mac book web cam and cam led light in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, webrtc, webcam

I am trying to turn off the connected MacBook webcam and cam-led lighting safari browser.

Here is my code

`myStream[0].getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())`

It works on Chrome but doesn't in Safari.

How do you turn off the green light of the webcam?
I looked at this part:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop

Comment: That's the way to do. Check that you didn't request several times the camera, that would be the most plausible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We can't turn off mac webcam greenlight manually if the webcam isn't turned off anymore according to apple's new policy. It will turn off if the webcam is not in use

Comment: but google meet is safari browser  turn off cam led possible.

Comment: oh, but Apple said in their latest software updates it won't be possible anymore. but there could be ways

Comment: then we can't controlled webcam device in safari browser?

Comment: When they call `VideoStreamTrack.stop()` the camera should be off, that "policy" doesn't apply here.

Comment: the question here is probably whether the webcam light stays on if there is a non-stopped audio track

Comment: @PhilippHancke not on my Safari 15.0 (16612.1.29.41.4, 16612) and neither on TP. They must have requested the MediaStream multiple times and lost track of one of these, but without more info from OP we can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the green light of the webcam is hardware controlled and not software controlled on latest MacBook.

Some additional information here  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313504/does-a-modern-macbooks-green-camera-light-always-turn-on-when-the-camera-is-a/396129

Comment: What ethical side? They stopped the track, the webcam is not being used anymore.

Comment: Oops correct, I edited my message.